# swift: Using or in a loop condition statement

Tags: swift, loops

sorry for asking a simple question, but unfortunately after an hour debugging I am a bit lost. I want to use "or" in the condition of a repeat while loop. Unfortunately the code just leave the loop when the first condition is true, the second seams to be never checked.

Here is my code:

```
j=1
repeat {
    if (Int(scores[1][j]) != 0) {
        if (nrOfMoves < Int(scores[1][j])) {
            positionToStore = j
            positionFound = true
        }
    } else {
           positionToStore = j
           positionFound = true
    }
    j++
} while(positionFound == false || j > 5)
```

while is just leaving when positionFound is true when j reaches 6 it just repeats or bette terminates by an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation:

> Repeat-While
>
> The other variation of the while loop, known as the repeat-while loop,
>   performs a single pass through the loop block first, before
>   considering the loop’s condition. It then continues to repeat the loop
>   until the condition is false.

It meens that your loop works only when condition `positionFound == false || j > 5` is `false`. When `positionFound` set to `true`, condition becomes `true` and you leave the loop.

In your situation you need to use `while` loop

From documentation:

> While
>
> A while loop starts by evaluating a single condition. If the condition
>   is true, a set of statements is repeated until the condition becomes
>   false.
>
> Here’s the general form of a while loop:

```
while positionFound == false || j > 5 {     
    if (Int(scores[1][j]) != 0) {
        if (nrOfMoves < Int(scores[1][j])) {
            positionToStore = j
            positionFound = true
        }
    } else {
       positionToStore = j
       positionFound = true
    }
    j++
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition in a `repeat-while` loop tells what needs to happen for the loop to continue.  You want to loop while `j <= 5` so that it drops out of that loop when `j` reaches `6`.  Also, you need to continue when both conditions hold, so in this case you should use `&&` instead of `||`.  With this change, the code then reads *"continue looping as long as I haven't found what I'm looking for AND my index is still good"*:

```
j=1
repeat {
    if (Int(scores[1][j]) != 0) {
        if (nrOfMoves < Int(scores[1][j])) {
            positionToStore = j
            positionFound = true
        }
    } else {
           positionToStore = j
           positionFound = true
    }
    j++
} while(positionFound == false && j <= 5)
```

---

A common shorthand way of writing `positionFound == false` is `!positionFound` and is pronounced *"not positionFound"*.